# Android long press search button not working

Tags: android

so my app listens for a long press on the search button and is supposed to be called in lieu of the normal voice search. I have the following:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.VOICE_COMMAND"/>
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

But the activity is not listed as an option when I long press the search button. Also, there are no defaults set for this action, so a list of possible activities to launch should populate, and they do; however, mine is not listed as one. Thoughts?

I have also tried to put the "android.intent.action.VOICE_COMMAND" in a receiver and in its own activity declaration in the manifest, but these do not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might answer your question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7922697/1259156

Comment: That worked. That's very strange because previous versions of my app used the "android.intent.action.VOICE_COMMAND" and worked fine. Thanks for the help!